# nativescript-vue - Adicionar um objeto em um array com push depois zerar o objeto adiciona um objeto zerado

Tags: javascript, vue.js, assincronismo, nativescript, array-push

Estou desenvolvendo um app com nativescript-vue onde possuo um cadastro de endereços.
Eu possuo os seguintes dados:

```js
        data() {
            return {
                isRegistering: true,
                enderecos: [{
                    id: 1,
                    descricao: 'Casa',
                    logradouro: 'Rua da minha casa',
                    numero: '123',
                    complemento: 'Apartamento 123 Bloco A',
                    bairro: 'Jardim Minha Casa',
                    cidade: 'Casa',
                    cep: '17200000'
                },{
                    id: 2,
                    descricao: 'Trabalho',
                    logradouro: 'Rua do meu Trabalho',
                    numero: '123',
                    complemento: "Dena Code S/A",
                    bairro: 'Jardim Trabalho',
                    cidade: 'Trabalho',
                    cep: '17200000'
                }],
                formEndereco: {
                    id: 0,
                    descricao: '',
                    logradouro: '',
                    numero: '',
                    complemento: '',
                    bairro: '',
                    cidade: '',
                    cep: '',
                }
            }
        },
```

Quando o usuário clica no botão Salvar insiro o meu formEndereco no array Enderecos:

```js
salvarEndereco() {
    this.enderecos.push(this.formEndereco);     
    this.limparFormEndereco();
},
limparFormEndereco() {
    this.formEndereco.id = 0;
    this.formEndereco.descricao = '';
    this.formEndereco.logradouro = '';
    this.formEndereco.numero = '';
    this.formEndereco.complemento = '';
    this.formEndereco.bairro = '';
    this.formEndereco.cep = '';
},
```

Aí vem o problema que está me quebrando a cuca hehe.
Se no método salvarEndereco eu apenas chamar a função "this.enderecos.push(this.formEndereco)", o endereço é inserido normalmente, porém quando adiciono o método "limparFormEndereco" em seguida é inserido o form vazio. Já tentei tornar o push uma função assíncrona, aquela gambiarra horrível de adicionar um time out na função de limpeza para que dê tempo de realizar o push mas nada resolveu até agora. Alguma dica do que posso não ter aprendido sobre o comportamento do vue ou do nativescript?

Esta é minha primeira pergunta no canal, me desculpem caso algo esteja muito errado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, pelo que percebo de javascript o que está a acontecer é que o teu array `enderecos` está a receber uma referencia de memória da tua variável `formEndereco` o que significa que caso tu modifiques a variavel `formEndereco` o teu array `enderecos` vai guardar é a modificação e não valor anterior.

A solução que vejo para isso é modificares a tua função desta forma:

ANTES:

```
salvarEndereco() {
    this.enderecos.push(this.formEndereco);     
    this.limparFormEndereco();
}
```

DEPOIS 1:

```
salvarEndereco() {
    this.enderecos.push(...this.formEndereco);     
    this.limparFormEndereco();
}
```

OU DEPOIS 2:

```
salvarEndereco() {
    const form = this.formEndereco;
    this.enderecos.push(form);     
    this.limparFormEndereco();
}
```

Se não te consegui ajudar com nenhuma das soluções em cima, pesquisa no google sobre isso:

[copia de objeto e referencias typescript - Google](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01wv3dvDkwObgX6lRyFi_Z9Tnwf4g%3A1584307969166&ei=AZ9uXqHoCdGdjLsPl6658AI&q=copia%20de%20objecto%20vs%20referencias%20typescript&oq=copia%20de%20objecto%20vs%20referencias%20type&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.33i160l2.6054.18361..19461...3.2..0.203.3771.5j24j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....10..0i71j35i362i39j35i39j0i131j0j0i67j0i131i67j0i203j0i22i30j0i13j0i13i30j0i19j0i22i30i19j0i13i30i19j0i13i5i30i19j0i8i13i30i19j0i13i5i30j0i8i13i30j33i22i29i30.4a3bfHL2HcM)

[Outras soluções](https://receitasdecodigo.com.br/typescript/clone-object-typescript)

Comment: A tua solução 1 tem um erro, deve ser `{...obj}` e não somente `...obj`. A tua segunda solução é o mesmo que o problema inicial, `form` aponta na mesma para o mesmo objeto. Corrige para `this.enderecos.push({...this.formEndereco});`